# Rails sort users by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to rank my user's in order of an integer. The integer I'm getting is in my User Model.

```
def rating_number
  Impression.where("impressionable_id = ?", self).count
end
```

This gives each User on the site a number (in integer form). Now, on the homepage, I want to show an ordered list that places these user's in order with the user with the highest number first and lowest number second. How can I accomplish this in the controller???

```
@users = User....???
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Using this in the controller

```
@users = User.all.map(&:rating_number)
```

and this for the view

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user %></li>
<% end %>
```

shows the user's count. Unfortunately, the variable `user` is acting as the integer not the user, so attaching `user.name` doesn't work. Also, the list isn't in order based on the integer..

Comment: What is the relationship between the `User` and the `Impression` model? Is it that `class User … has_many :impressions` and you want to sort the users by number of impressions?

Comment: Yea sort by number of impressions (plus a few other integers I'll get like number of likes they have on their Posts, etc). I'm using the Impressionist Gem (https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist), which logs actions in the controller. The way it related to the User model is by the impressionable_id which is the user's id of the page you are viewing...

Comment: You can use `where(impressionable_id: id)`, you don't need to use a string for `where` if you're doing straight equality. Also, user is "acting like an integer" because you're mapping them to integers. What do you think `map(&:rating_number)` does? Why are you using that if you don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The advice here is *still* all kinds of wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617734/229044); all other answers will perform terribly. Trying to do this via a nested `select count(*)` is almost as bad an idea as using `User.all` and sorting in memory.

The correct way to do this if you want it to work on a reasonably large data set is to use [counter caches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) and stop trying to order by the count of a related record.

- Add a `rating_number` column to the `users` table, and make sure it has an index defined on it
- Add a counter cache to your `belongs_to`:

  ```
  class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :rating_number
  end
  ```

  Now creating/deleting impressions will modify the associated user's `rating_number`.
- Order your results by `rating_number`, dead simple:

  ```
  User.order(:rating_number)
  ```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the advice! It's definitely appreciated, as I am relatively new to things and am still trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: You're welcome. The key idea to take away here is that sometimes it's faster to spend a little more time on *writing* records (like updating a counter cache) than it is to take an order of magnitude more time when *reading* records (trying to compute `rating_number` in real time).

Comment: Yea that seems logical. Thanks @meagar

Comment: Just finished implementing the advice you gave me. Works like a charm, and helped me learn some more rails. Big time appreciate it @meagar.

Comment: @Justin Note that you may have to "seed" your rating column with a query up-front. Existing records will not have a correct cached `rating_number`.

Comment: Yea I noticed this. I could always just set the default to 0..would this be the same?

Comment: Also, you gave me the query `User.order(:rating_number)`. Assuming it's not hard to figure out, how can i change this to get the user with the highest rating...You see, in my design I hightlight the first user then just show a basic list with every user besides the first. (using two different variables in the controller: one for the first user, and one for the rest of the users).

Comment: `User.order('rating_number DESC').first` will give you the highest rated user. And you can set all `rating_number` to `0`, but that won't be correct for users with existing Impressions. You can set it to the correct number with a simple SQL query or Rails console command: `User.find_each { |u| u.update_column(:rating_number, u.impressions.count) }`

Comment: Good thing it's still in production so there are no existing users :).

Answer (score 1):

The advice here is just all kinds of wrong. First of model your associations correctly. Secondly you dont ever want to do User.all and then sort it in-memory based on anything. How do you think it will perform with lots of records?

What you want to do is query your user rows and sort them based on a subquery that counts impressions for that user.

```
User.order("(SELECT COUNT(impressions.id) FROM impressions WHERE impressionable_id = users.id) DESC")
```

While this is not terribly efficient, it is still much more efficient than operating with data sets in memory. The next step is to cache the impressions count on the user itself (a la counter cache), and then use that for sorting.

It just pains me that doing User.all is the first suggestion...

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that without writing raw SQL? I don't disagree about the performance implications of User.all, but I thought that was only if you were updating an attribute or something. The SQL generated with the method I gave looked like it grabbed all Users first.

Comment: Not really no, ActiveRecord is built for mostly easy things. I would say it's fine to resort to pure SQL if it is more efficient or just makes more sense. In this case if nails both points in my opinion.

Comment: And as far as User.all goes, this really does not have anything to do with updating. User.all queries for all records from your table, loads the row data and constructs AR object instances in memory. If you have 500 000 records, it generates 500 00 model instances - I suggest you try it out just once out of curiosity and see how it performs :)

Comment: Thanks to all who gave suggestions and advice here. It's must appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

If `impressions` is a column in your `users` table, you can do

`User.order('impressions desc')`

#### Edit

Since it's not a column in your users table, you can do this:

```
User.all.each(&:rating_number).sort {|x,y| y <=> x }
```

#### Edit

Sorry, you want this:

```
User.all.sort { |x, y| y.rating_number <=> x.rating_number }
```

Comment: Oops. I didn't see your edit until after I answered. Sounds like `impressions` is not a field in your `users` table.

Comment: Getting SO close! That's getting the list of the user's but it's not putting them in the correct order! The order is random right now, from 1-4 the numbers are [439, 49, 200, 2102]

Comment: This sorts the User's based on their `ID`, not on their `rating_number`... I'm going to keep trying to figure it out. If you are able to get the answer, please let me know!

Comment: This is the worst possible solution for this problem. You are loading the entire set of users into memory, then querying and instantiating Impression records for each user yielding a huge N+1, which is *especially* wasteful since you just want the `count` of the records; there is no reason to instantiate entire Impression instances. Then you're sorting in-memory to produce the final set of records.